# Mapping over JavaScript object fetched from Express server in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, dictionary, typeerror

I have multiple arrays inside of an object, for different types of micronutrients (Vitamins, Minerals, Antioxidants, AminoAcids, and Omegas). I want each one to passed as an `<option>` inside of their own dropdown menu that displays their own type (Ex. Vitamins: Vitamin B2, B6, B5, etc.)

My console shows that the data has been fetched successfully:

```
{vitamins: Array(6), minerals: Array(2), aminoacids: Array(1), antioxidants: Array(2), omegas: Array(1)}
```

But when I get to the Vitamins.js, where I'm trying to render the option's, it says "TypeError: vitamins.map is not a function".

Here is my res.json from my Express server:

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.json({vitamins: [
  {
    name: "Vitamin B2"
  },
  {
    name: "Vitamin B6"
  }, 
  {
    name: "Vitamin B5"
  }
],
 minerals: [
  {
    name: "Calcium"
  },
 {
  name: "Zinc"
  }
 ] 
});
});
```

Here is where the state is being declared for the res.json in Home.js. (I know "users" doesn't make any semantic sense right now, and I will change it. Just trying to figure out why it's not working first.)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {users: []};
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
 }

 render() {
   return (
      <MenuItems users={this.state.users} />
  )
}
```

This is Menuitems.js, one level down from Home.js, where I'm calling the handleChange function so when a user clicks on a new micro (Vitamin B2 -> B6) the new micro (B6) becomes the new selected option.

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {
    value: '',
  };

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
   this.setState({
      value: value
   });
 }

 render() {
  return (
    <ul className="menuitems">
      <li>
        <Vitamins data={this.props.users} />
      </li>
      <li>
         <Minerals data={this.props.users} />
       </li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

And this is Vitamins.js (I also have Minerals.js, AminoAcids.js, etc.), where I'm trying to map over the "vitamins" array in my res.json object, and pull each name inside of the select dropdown.

```
  renderData() {
    const vitamins = this.props.data;
    console.log("the data", vitamins);
    return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
     return (
       <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
     )
   })
 }

  render() {
   return (
    <form>
      <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="" selected>--Vitamins--</option>
        {this.renderData()}
      </select>
    </form>
  )
 }
```

The console.log in renderData() will show nothing at first, but after componentDidMount() it shows this TWICE

```
 the data {vitamins: Array(6), minerals: Array(2), aminoacids: Array(1), antioxidants: Array(2), omegas: Array(1)}
```

**EDIT**

I took some of the advice I was given, and tried applying it.

This one worked, where I declared state inside of each child component (Vitamins, Minerals, etc.)

```
 state = {users: []};

 componentDidMount() {
   fetch('/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(users => {
      this.setState({
        users: users.vitamins
      });
    })
  }

 renderData() {
   const vitamins = this.state.users;
   return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
   return (
      <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
    )
  })
}
```

However, I don't want to have to keep fetching in each component. I tried declaring state in the parent MenuItems, and passing {this.state.users.vitamins} in the data props as suggested.

```
(MenuItems.js)

state = {users: []};

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(users => {
     this.setState({
       users
     });
   })
 }

render() {
  return (
    <ul className="menuitems">
      <li>
        <Vitamins data={this.state.users.vitamins} />
      </li>
    </ul>
 )
}

(Vitamins.js)

 renderData() {
   const vitamins = this.props.data;
   return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
     return (
       <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
     )
   })
 }
```

But, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when I do this.

If I do "const { vitamins } = this.props.data", I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'vitamins' of undefined".

So how do I fetch at the parent level, and pass the only array I need into data= ?

Comment: try `const { vitamins } = this.props.data` or: `<Vitamins data={this.props.users.vitamins} />` + `this.state = { users: {} };`

Comment: Seems that @riwu is correct.Data passed to Vitamins.js is a parent branch of the vitamins array

Comment: This is a lot of code, most of which should be entirely irrelevant: what comes in as props and state for your Vitamins component? Because that's the only part that matters: if it gets a plain object, then it's 100% obvious why `.map()` fails. Do a `console.log(this.props)` in that vitamin render function, see what you actually put in it, and then work your way back.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If I split users here `<Vitamins data={this.state.users.vitamins} />` , I get back "undefined" in the console.log from the render function in Vitamins.js. If I do `<Vitamins data={this.state.users} />`, I get back the entire users object in the console.log `{vitamins: Array(6), minerals: Array(2), aminoacids: Array(1), antioxidants: Array(2), omegas: Array(1)}`.

Comment: So, reduce that, drastically. Do a console.log of `this.state.users` before you build Vitamins: copy that string, throw away EVERYTHING ELSE you have, make a `class App extends React.Component { render() { let userstate = JSON.parse("...that string..."); return <Vitamins data={userstate}/>; } }`, and see what happens. This is why the advice is typically to form an [mcve]: almost none of the code you showed is necessary to actually test what your Vitamin class is doing. And if that's behaving fine, we repeat the excercise, one component higher (capture the data as JSON, feed it directly).

Answer (score 1):

You are currently fetching only the users. In vitamins.js you try to fetch the data from the this.props.data, which will give you the information that you are dealing with arrays, as seen in your console log. You need to "split" your data before you can fetch it.

```
this.setState({ users: users.vitamins)}
```

for example ( i dont know your ecosystem, so whatever you are trying to fetch needs to be associated in the setState event, otherwise you simply passing data without a data definition).

As one already posted in the comment section, you could also try to split it when you pass the data to the component:

```
    <Vitamins data={this.props.users.vitamins}
```

Its basically the same, you take the users and fetch the vitamin data. Whenever you want to map an array, you have to "open" it up.

Here is a basic example, how you would normally do it:

```
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.users.your-data-you-want-to-fetch.map((x) => {

    this.setState({
      vitamin: x.name,
      id: x.id,
      })
```

}))

data.vitamin / data.id will be then accessible for your props data.

Greetings!